# How can I make SELECT COUNT(*) return 0 in a GROUP BY query if no rows are found

Tags: t-sql

I'm looking to write a query that grabs a count of a field and groups it together, but I want it to return ALL values even if the count is 0.

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
      ,PMI
  FROM Items AS AA
  JOIN Headers AS BB
  ON AA.DocID = BB.ID
 WHERE (DocDate = CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE() - 1, 1) AS datetime))
   AND PMI != ''
GROUP BY PMI
```

Here's what I want to see:

```
COUNT     PMI
    1     900330
    5     900702
    0     900550
    0     900331
```

But here's what I'm getting:

```
COUNT     PMI
    1     900330
    5     900702
```

I've never had to write a query to accomplish this before so I apologize if this is trivial.

EDIT: I realized that these tables do not contain all of the items I am looking for. I have a lookup table called 'lookup' which contains all of these items I wish to query for counts.

EDIT 2: Thanks everyone. Made it work by creating a view and using the lookup table and an outer join. Did the trick wonderfully.

Comment: Please show other column values especially `AA.DocID` and `BB.ID`

Comment: Is `PMI` part of the `Items` table or the `Headers` table?

Comment: PMI is part of the Items table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an `INNER JOIN` which returns no row if the match fials. You should use an `OUTER JOIN` instead.

Assuming that `PMI` is on `Items`:

```
SELECT PMI, COUNT(BB.ID)
  FROM Items AS AA
  LEFT JOIN Headers AS BB
  ON AA.DocID = BB.ID
 WHERE (DocDate = CAST(CONVERT(varchar(8), GETDATE() - 1, 1) AS datetime))
   AND PMI != ''
GROUP BY PMI
```

Comment: I had a brain fart...I realized that not all of the items I want to return are in either table but in another seperate table called 'lookup'.

Comment: I believe it also could be RIGHT JOIN, depends on ID's values, right?

Comment: I figured that but I could not get it to work. I'll take another stab

Answer (score 3):

Easy answer is wrap the whole SQL query and add a SUM on the COUNT column.

```
SELECT SUM(yourCountField), someOtherField1, someOtherField2
FROM
(
    SELECT COUNT(yourCountField), someOtherField1, someOtherField2
    FROM ....
)
GROUP BY someOtherField1, someOtherField2
```

Comment: `yourCountField`... indeed ! So obvious that sometimes I still don't remember how to do that !